# What the difference between lambda-local and AWS Sam CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

There are lambda-local and AWS Sam CLI. I don't understand what the difference.

Both can test functions on the local machine. The only advantage of AWS SAM I can see that it can make use of SAM template for deployment and it has local Dynamodb.

I think both can use AWS SDK module to connect through AWS services like SNS, SQS and Dynamodb.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that these two projects are created and maintained by different persons. The [AWS SAM CLI](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli) is supported by AWS itself (though it's 'only' a Labs project). SAM CLI is using Docker in the background to start and execute your function code. It's also supporting multiple languages for your Lambda function, e.g. Java, NodeJS, Python, etc. The [lambda-local](https://github.com/ashiina/lambda-local) project seems to only use a native NodeJS approach, i.e. only NodeJS Lambda functions can be executed/tested.

If you only decide between those two projects, then my suggestion is to go with AWS SAM CLI, because it supports more aspects of the development lifecycle and integrates nicely with CloudFormation/SAM.